# Reading and parsing large delimited text files in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-import

I'm busy with an applicaton which reads space delimited log files ranging from 5mb to 1gb+ in size, then stores this information to a MySQL database for later use when printing reports based upon the information contained in the files. The methods I've tried / found work but are very slow.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a better way to handle very large text files?

I've tried using textfieldparser as follows:

```
Using parser As New TextFieldParser("C:\logfiles\testfile.txt")
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
    parser.CommentTokens = New String() {"#"}
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {" "}
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    While Not parser.EndOfData
        Dim input As String() = parser.ReadFields()
        If input.Length = 10 Then
            'add this to a datatable
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

This works but is very slow for the larger files.

I then tried using an OleDB connection to the text file as per the following function in conjunction with a schema.ini file I write to the directory beforehand:

```
Function GetSquidData(ByVal logfile_path As String) As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim myData As New DataSet
    Dim strFilePath As String = ""
    If logfile_path.EndsWith("\") Then
        strFilePath = logfile_path
    Else
        strFilePath = logfile_path & "\"
    End If
    Dim mySelectQry As String = "SELECT * FROM testfile.txt WHERE Client_IP <> """""
    Dim myConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;""")
        Dim dsCmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mySelectQry, myConnection)
        dsCmd.Fill(myData, "logdata")
        If Not myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    Return myData.Tables("logdata")
End Function
```

The schema.ini file:

```
[testfile.txt]
Format=Delimited( )
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Timestamp text
Col2=Elapsed text
Col3=Client_IP text
Col4=Action_Code text
Col5=Size double
Col6=Method text
Col7=URI text
Col8=Ident text
Col9=Hierarchy_From text
Col10=Content text
```

Anyone have any ideas how to read these files faster?

-edit-
Corrected a typo in the code above

Comment: You might look into using [logparser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser) rather than trying to implement it yourself.

Comment: Are these methods reading in the entire file at once? If you watch the memory of your program is it shooting up past the size of the file you're reading in (500MB-1GB)? If so you probably need to use a method of reading the file that can read the files one line at a time.

Comment: @AakashM Thanks will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two potentially slow operations there:

- File reading
- Inserting lots of data into the db

Separate them and test which is taking the most time. I.e. write one test program that simply reads the file, and another test program that just inserts loads of records. See which one is slowest.

One problem could be that you are reading the whole file into memory?

Try reading it line by line with a Stream. Here is a [code example copied from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx#Y47)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Try
            ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            Using sr As New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
                Dim line As String
                ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                ' the file is reached.
                Do
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    If Not (line Is Nothing) Then
                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                    End If
                Loop Until line Is Nothing
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            ' Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer MarkJ, I cant open the link you provided :( think my ISP may be having some issues today...

I have tried this using a streamreader.readline function but don't see that it makes much difference (and also with the larger of the files I get a system.outofmemory exception). Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @DonnavandeGroot I have copied the code example from the link into my answer. I also edited my answer to suggest you carry out some experiments to determine whether the file reading or the database insertions are the bottleneck. That's what I would do first

Comment: Thanks for updating your post :) I tried using the stream reader but I receive system.outofmemory exceptions :( Also I've split the jobs completely now and its definitely the reading of the files that is taking extremely long

Comment: @DonnavandeGroot Out of memory exceptions? Are you storing the whole file contents in memory? I would strongly advise against that. I read in and process a single line at a time

Comment: I was writing each line to a dataset then using the dataset to update a MySQL innodb database using a transaction to try cut down on time spent doing database insertions. Should I rather insert each line indivdually? or build the transaction while reading the file (therefore no need for the dataset)?  <<think i may hav just answered myself there...

Comment: @DonnavandeGroot I think you have answered yourself! Just build the transaction while reading the file. You are already storing a large amount of data in two locations (original file and database), no need to introduce a third location (in-memory copy of all the data).

Answer (score -2):

From the top of my head id say try to impelement some kind of threading to spread the workload.

Comment: Most likely what is causing speed issues is disk activity and not CPU limitations so threading is most likely of no help.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea but I would have to agree with CodyC on the above. Unless there is perhaps a way to split the file into x number of lines segments then let different threads handle each segment of the file? Would this even be possible / viable?  [would need to split by lines though as each line is a complete record and cant risk losing data by having incomplete lines]